# Error al usar Global Hooks en C#

Tags: c#

Buen día a todos,

Estoy teniendo problemas para utilizar la clase UserActivityHook, cuando intento abrir el formulario donde llamo a la clase me lanza este error:

- The specified module could not be found.
- Win32 Exception was unhandled by user code.

[image: Error]

El ejemplo que proporcionan en la página, me funciona sin problemas, pero importe la clase a mi proyecto e hice las instancias correspondientes y me arroja ese error que comente arriba.
El ejemplo veo que esta en Net 2.0 yo estoy trabajando en Net 4 y no me funciona, de hecho probe con Net 2.0 y 3.5 en mi proyecto y siguen sin funcionar.
He leido algunos hilos relacionados, pero tampoco me han funcionado, alguna sugerencia al respecto?

O alternativas para capturar eventos globales del Mouse y Teclado, no quisiera llegar a cambiar el codigo pero si no hay solucion a esto creo tendre que realizarlo, pero desconozco que otras alternativas existan.

El ejemplo lo saque de aqui:

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

El error me lo esta dando en estas lineas de código:

```
 public void Start(bool InstallMouseHook, bool InstallKeyboardHook)
    {
        // install Mouse hook only if it is not installed and must be installed
        if (hMouseHook == 0 && InstallMouseHook)
        {
            // Create an instance of HookProc.
            MouseHookProcedure = new HookProc(MouseHookProc);
            //install hook
            hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_MOUSE_LL,
                MouseHookProcedure,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);
            //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
            if (hMouseHook == 0)
            {
                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //do cleanup
                Stop(true, false, false);
                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);//<--Error
            }
        }
```

Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Mi sistema operativo en Windows 10 PRO de 64 BITS y Visual Studio 2010.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

DS